# SurfaceView drawText flickering

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am trying to make a simple stopwatch using a `SurfaceView`. It shows hundredths of a second, so it tries to update as often as possible in order to keep a smooth animation. It works absolutely fine on my tablet running 4.0.3 and my phone running 4.0.4, but when I try it on 4.4.4, there appears to be some tearing I cannot explain.

[image: This is an emulator running 4.4.4, but the problem happens on a hardware device as well.]

The bottom image shows what should be happening, and for the most part it works. However, once every few seconds there is a flicker. When I manage to pause at the right time, I see that *some* of the digits are transposed to the right. They only ever move to the right (a la the top image). This only happens for a fraction of a second, just long enough to cause a noticeable flicker.

Note that the digits are positioned on the canvas using values calculated once (in `onMeasure()`) and stored in class fields. They do not change after they are initialized. I tested this by logging the pixel values of each inside `onDraw()`.

In the image above it is the minutes values that are transposed, but sometimes it is the other digits. They always seem to be transposed in a set; both the minutes, both the seconds or both the centiseconds.

**Further: this only affects `drawText()`.** I have more complex versions of this stopwatch with lots of paths, circles, etc. The problem only happens with text.

I looked at several questions and comments on SO and elsewhere. Here's what I have determined:

- I do not think it is a buffer issue. The behaviour seems similar to
  descriptions of buffer-based tearing, but in this case I don't think
  the problem can be old data being posted to the screen, because the
  digits are *never* drawn in the positions they are shown.
- I read in a comment that it might be related to the function that
  updates the values being called more than once between the `onDraw()`
  method calls. I have tried throttling the update, but the problem
  persists.
- I also tried drawing to a temporary bitmap and using `canvas.drawBitmap()` in
  the `onDraw()` function, again to no avail.

Basically, I want to know:

- **What is causing this issue?**
- **Why is it only in higher versions of Android?**
- **What can I do about it?**

Comment: Sounds like it's not "flickering" so much as occasionally drawing text in the wrong place. When you said you drew to a temporary bitmap "to no avail" does that mean you continued to see the minute digits rendering in the wrong place? Is it always the minute digits? Grab a recording with `screenrecord`, and walk through it frame-by-frame. Do the counters progress forward, or do they jump backward when the frame is drawn incorrectly? Overriding `onDraw()` to draw on a SurfaceView is a bad idea; rename the function, get rid of "@Override", and confirm that the problem still happens.

Comment: I did try putting the drawing in a custom method, which fixed the issue but caused a massive drop in framerate, so I went back to using onDraw. I'll try recording as you suggest.

Comment: If you're using `onDraw()`, then when the app framework refreshes the View UI you'll be drawing on the View (like a custom View would) rather than the Surface. The View overlaps the Surface, so you're drawing on two overlapping layers. The size of the Surface does not have to be the same as the size of the View, so using `onMeasure()` is inappropriate (see `SurfaceHolder#setFixedSize()`). You should probably be using a custom View instead: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: Interesting... I did try using a custom view originally, but the framerate was never high enough to make the animation look smooth.

Comment: In order of decreasing speed: (1) rendering onto a SurfaceView Surface with OpenGL; (2) rendering onto a hardware-accelerated custom View with Canvas; (3) rendering onto a SurfaceView Surface with Canvas. Not all Canvas operations can be done in hardware on all versions of Android; see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html .

Answer (score 1):

After reading @fadden's comments, I was able to search a bit more effectively.

It seems that my error was in trying to call `onDraw()` in the animation thread.  When I changed that one call to `postInvalidate()`, it immediately fixed the problem. In short, the inside of the animation loop looks like this:

```
holder = view.getHolder();
canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
if (canvas != null) {
    synchronized (holder) {
        if (view != null) {
            view.DEBUG_THREADCALLS++;
            // NOT view.onDraw(), but:
            view.postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, the call to `onDraw()` causes problems because it results in the app drawing to both the `View` and the `Surface`.

I am guessing that the reason the problem only showed up in the more modern versions of Android might be because the newer devices have higher refresh rates, and so the problem was simply more visible. I have noticed that the solution also significantly increased the framerate on my oldest device, which is presumably because it is not working so hard drawing to two places at once.

---

**UPDATE**

Following further advice from the extremely helpful comments below, I have removed the SurfaceView altogether and am now drawing on a custom View using a separate animation Thread. The result is unbelievably smooth animation even on older devices, far better than the SurfaceView! So to anyone else trying to animate with a SurfaceView, I say: Unless you have a very good reason to, don't!

Comment: Since you're not using the `canvas`, you can delete all of the code except for `view.postInvalidate()`.

Comment: Oh, wow. So literally all I need to do is create a separate thread that just posts invalidate? No faffing around locking the canvas? Why do so many tutorials use onDraw in the way I was before...?

Comment: Many SurfaceView tutorials are completely wrong. (Which reminds me, you can now change SurfaceView to View, since you're not using the Surface at all.)

Comment: Would that not result in more jerky animation? I think the original reason I went with SurfaceView is because somewhere in the Android spec it mentioned that high-framerate animation is better done with a SurfaceView. Anyway, I'll give it a shot and see what happens. How did you come to know so much about this stuff? Can you recommend any good resources? Or is it just experience?

Comment: I used to work for Google (click my name to see my profile). I recommend reading https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html to understand how the pieces fit together.